# Display the Answer to a Previous Q in gApps Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like a question in my form to display the answer to a previous question. I am not asking about question logic or the Go To feature.
For example:

Q1: What type of entree would you like?
Meat
Fish
Vegetarian

Q2: Which cuisine do you prefer?
Indian
American
Mexican

Page break.

Q3: In the previous questions, you selected an [Q2] [Q1] entree.

If the answer to Q1 was Meat and to Q2 was Indian, then Q3 should display:

In the previous questions, you selected an Indian Meat entree.

This is possible in SurveyMonkey (with the use of square brackets). Can this be done in Google Forms?

Comment: In SurveyMonkey I do not know, in Google Apps Script you defenitly can. Client side solution, you can construct Q3 with all the possible options in several labels putting them all to NOT visible when a chois is made you make that option visible. And with server side script you can construct the Q3 in base of what was answered in Q1 and Q2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jacobvdb. Can you or anyone else provide more information on what this kind of script would look like? I don't have any experience with Google Apps Script.

Comment: I´ll place one a little bid later if no one else answers before. No wurries (I´m at work now).

Answer (score 0):

I've written some dirty code in the boss´ time

It's a mix of server and client side script, I could have created the question Q3 in the function q1H & q2H.

```
 var q1A = new Array(" Meat", " Fish", " Vegetarian")
 var q2A = new Array(" Indian" ," American", " Mexican")

function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Dev Test Sitemap");
var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
var homePanel = app.createHorizontalPanel()

 var q1 = app.createLabel("Q1 What type of entree would you like?")
 var q1ListBox = app.createListBox().setName("q1ListBox") ;
  for (var i = 0; i < q1A.length; i++) {
    q1ListBox.addItem(q1A[i]);
  }

  var handlerQ1 = app.createServerHandler("q1H");
  q1ListBox.addChangeHandler(handlerQ1)

  mainPanel.add(q1);
 mainPanel.add(q1ListBox);

  var q2 = app.createLabel("Q2 Indian American Mexican?")
  var q2ListBox = app.createListBox().setName("q2ListBox") ;
  for (var i = 0; i < q2A.length; i++) {
     q2ListBox.addItem(q2A[i]);
   }

   var handlerQ2 = app.createServerHandler("q2H");
   q2ListBox.addChangeHandler(handlerQ2)

   mainPanel.add(q2);
   mainPanel.add(q2ListBox);


   mainPanel.add(app.createLabel("----------------------------------- pagebreak ---------------------") );

  var horP = app.createHorizontalPanel()
  //Q3: In the previous questions, you selected an [Q2] [Q1] entree.
  var  q3 = app.createLabel("In the previous questions, you selected an")
  horP.add(q3)

  var q2ans =new Array() 
  for (var i = 0; i < q2A.length; i++) {
     q2ans[i] = app.createLabel(q2A[i]).setId("q2A"+[i]).setVisible(false);
     horP.add(q2ans[i])

  }
   var q1ans =new Array() ;
   for (var i = 0; i < q1A.length; i++) {
     q1ans[i] = app.createLabel(q1A[i]).setId("q1A"+[i]).setVisible(false);
     horP.add(q1ans[i])
   }

   var  q32 = app.createLabel(" entree")
   horP.add(q32)

   mainPanel.add(horP);

   app.add(mainPanel);  //red
  return app.close();
 } 


 function q1H(e) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var q1ListBox =   e.parameter.q1ListBox;



   for (var i = 0; i < q1A.length; i++) {
     if (q1ListBox == q1A[i] ){
       app.getElementById("q1A"+[i]).setVisible(true);
    }

  }

    return app;
  }

  function q2H(e) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var q2ListBox =   e.parameter.q2ListBox;

    for (var i = 0; i < q2A.length; i++) {
     if (q2ListBox == q2A[i] ){
      app.getElementById("q2A"+[i]).setVisible(true);
     }

     }

  return app;
  }
```

[Working example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/home/dev-test-q1-q2-q3)

Comment: Thank you. That's a little complicated for my skill level, but I am trying to follow it. Does this example mean that I would have to hard code all of my questions into the script? I was hoping to be able to use the web interface to create the form and then somehow invoke the answer to a previous question when writing a new question.

Comment: Yep in the begining it might be a bid comlicated though following the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) and working on a script you'll note that you can reuse a lot of code and make it more sofisticated than the regular form and make it totally integrated with other sistems. Also recomend to always have the [Google Apps Dev](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/) site at hand! And of course STO for help :-)